# Count the amount of matching results between two buckets

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with the following fields:

- "distributorId". Contains the id of a distributor or the value "icecat". The amount of unique values for this field is around 20.
- "mpn". Contains an identifier for a product. This contains a high number of unique values.

Products by mpn can exist for multiple distributorIds, or they could exist for "icecat".

Now I want to know how many of the MPNs that exist for non-"icecat" *also* exist for "icecat".

How do I approach this?